# Adding an image and a JLabel in a new JLabel

Tags: java, jlabel

I am making a quiz in Java. Right now i'm trying to make the final screen with the results. I want to have a table with in the first column an image, in the second column the right answer and in the last column the given answer. I'm having trouble with adding the image and the given answer. Below there is the part of the code where I make the table:

```
        ImageIcon image1 = new ImageIcon("images/Zwitserland.png");

        FinalTekst = new JLabel ("<html>"
                                    + "<p style='text-align:center;'>Je bent klaar met de quiz. Je hebt in totaal <strong>"+CorrAntw+"</strong> van de 10 vragen goed.</p>"
                                    + "<table border='0'>"
                                        + "<tr><th> </th><th>Correct antwoord</th><th>Gegeven antwoord</th></tr>"
                                        + "<tr><td>"+image1+"</td><td>Zwitserland</td><td>"+Antw1+"</td></tr>"
                                    + "</table>"
                                + "</html>");
        FinalTekst.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        FinalTekst.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        add(FinalTekst, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

image1 is shown as the text "images/Zwitserland.png". Below is the code for Antw1, which is shown as a very long text.

```
        if (event.getSource() == bv1a) {
            Antw1 = new JLabel ("Zwitserland");
        }
        else if (event.getSource() == bv1b) {
            Antw1 = new JLabel ("Bahrein");
        }
        else if (event.getSource() == bv1c) {
            Antw1 = new JLabel ("Oostenrijk");
        }
        else if (event.getSource() == bv1d) {
            Antw1 = new JLabel ("Turkije");
        }
        else {
            Antw1 = new JLabel ("Geen antwoord");
        }
```

Can someone please help me with adding the given answer and the image? I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using html to set the image in your label, you can just use

`myLabel.setImageIcon(new ImageIcon("path_to_your_icon"));`

In this case, you can use two labels or more one for the question, and the second for the answer.

Also you need to update your user interface to adapt it with your html added in the label